# How do you pass a lot of data into a view that doesn't need to persist in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I know that you could use a service or an HTTP call to a database to get the data you want in a view.

And I know that you could access data in the URL as parameters or via the query string.

But what if you want to pass - 1) a lot of data, 2) that doesn't need to persist - into a view?

For example, I have a form for creating a Thing, and I want the user to be able to preview the Thing. I already have a show view for Thing, and there's too much to display for a modal or to display it on the same page.

- It seems unnecessary to use a service, and definitely doesn't seem necessary to use a database.
- It seems excessive to pass it in via the URL.
- Maybe you could use [$sessionStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)?

Thoughts? Is there a best practice here?

Comment: How much is a 'lot'? What is that data? Why u can not display it 'on same page'? (In the means of angular, where total application is often one page)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov assume that it is indeed a lot and that I don't want to show it in the same *view* (you're right - technically it is all the same page) for UI reasons.

Comment: well u always define in rootscope/your top scope model.damnHugeDataArray, fill it and change state, then clean it when u want

Answer (score 0):

Using a service is in fact a good idea. The first "view" set the service data, the other get it.

Or, if that answers what you mean by "without persisting the data", you could simply emit the data from one view (controller/directive/service) to another.

View1:

```
$scope.$root.$broadcast('bigdata', data);
```

View2:

```
$scope.$on('bigdata', function(e, data) {
  // Deal with the data which is garbage collected at the end of this callback
});
```